# Cast array with returned value from an array function in VBA

Tags: arrays, function, vba

I am just unsure on the syntax of the following problem. I have an function in which I need to pass in a value and then return an array.

```
Function billable(val As String) As Variant()

    Dim arr(1 To 3) As Variant
    arr(1) = Left(val, 1)
    arr(2) = Left(val, 2)
    arr(3) = Left(val, 3)
    billable = Application.Transpose(arr)

End Function
```

My question is, in another procedure how do I get the values from returned billable() array but yet pass the string val into it at the same time?

eg

```
myDesiredValue1 = billable((val),1)
myDesiredValue2 = billable((val),2)
myDesiredValue3 = billable((val),3)
```

Just to point out though, if I have to use an interim array variable, that's not a problem. I gave that approach a go but couldn't work it out either :(

Cheers

Chris

Comment: Here myDesiredValue1 = billable((val),1) you are passing two arguments. I think an error would be comeing.

Comment: did you try `myDesiredValue1 = billable(val)(1)`?

Comment: @Brain Yeah, I was just trying to give an example but you are right though :)

Comment: If you are calling these one after the other cache the result of  single call; `mybillable = billable(val) ... myDesiredValue1 = mybillable(a,b)`

Comment: @Ioannis. Sorry no luck there. Get a 'subscript out of range' error

Comment: @Ioannis My bad, forgot the 2 dimensional call. It should be billable(val)(1,1)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
Dim arr(1 To 3) As Variant
Dim myDesiredValue1 As Variant
Dim val As String

Function billable(val As String) As Variant()

    arr(1) = Left(val, 1)
    arr(2) = Left(val, 2)
    arr(3) = Left(val, 3)
    billable = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Function

Public Sub checkTest()
    val = "Hello"
myDesiredValue1 = billable(val)
myDesiredValue2 = billable(val)
myDesiredValue3 = billable(val)
For i = 1 To UBound(myDesiredValue1)
    Debug.Print myDesiredValue1(i, 1)
    Debug.Print myDesiredValue2(i, 1)
    Debug.Print myDesiredValue3(i, 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a follows

```
billable(val)(1,1)
```